# How can I make a complex tartan pattern in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, patterns

Could anyone tell me how to create the tartan design shown in the attached file? Im using Illustrator CS6

[image]

Comment: So the basic principle will be: do what they say on [How can I make a Tartan Design in Adobe Illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18067/how-can-i-make-a-tartan-design-in-adobe-illustrator) to create the diagonal textures, then make long horizontal and vertical rectangles with those textures and blend modes and overlay them over each other.