# Get a pattern to apply on other shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns

[image]

I am trying to get the pink checker pattern to go on top of the red shapes. I have been trtried using the minus front, minus back, etc. I tried to do a clipping mask, but I might not be doing it right. Please help!

Comment: Does your flower decal have a transparent background? You won't be able to do what you want if "Layer 2" has a solid white background with the flower design.

Comment: No it doesn't. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Select Layer 2, use the magic wand tool and select the red/pink part. Go to selection -> similar. This will select similar colors in the decal, make a new layer and fill the selection with the color you want. Make a clipping mask of the new layer decal with the pattern above that layer.

Answer (score 1):

Select the red shapes.. choose `Object > Compound Path > Make`

Move the red shapes *above* the checkers **on the same layer**.

Select the red and the checkers and choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`

That should do it.

An easier solution would be to make a pattern swatch of the checkers, then just fill the red shapes with the pattern.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much! If I want to make this again, how would I go about making a pattern swatch of the checkers?

Comment: While a bit more complex [**THIS QUESTION** (click me)](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18067/how-can-i-make-a-tartan-design-in-adobe-illustrator) covers a checkered pattern creation in Illustrator, @help