# How can I create a fine diagonal stripe pattern with Adobe design tools?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

I wanted to recreate this fine stripe pattern - see dark bar behind the logo on top card:

[image]

I started copy / pasting 90 dregree single stripes at set distances from each other manually, however in the copy and paste stage I quickly lost track of the distance since the width of multiple stripes + width of all margins becomes a confusing factor in copy / pasting the groups.

So I came here to learn how to create this effect in InDesign or Illustrator or even Photoshop.

**How is this done?**

Comment: You should pick an app.. because it's different in each of them.

Comment: Are you asking how to make this on a literal physical printed card, or are you asking how to fake it in a mockup photo?

Comment: @DA01 Seems obvious to me. I said: "I wanted to recreate this fine stripe pattern" - Not "I want to recreate these business cards laying on cement texture"

Comment: @JonathanTodd while it may be obvious to you, it's not to us because a lot of people come here asking how to create fake mockups. Which is a perfectly valid question as well, but as you realize, something different. Thanks for clarifying. I'll add an answer.

Comment: Possibly related for Illustrator: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18067/how-can-i-make-a-tartan-design-in-adobe-illustrator

Comment: Make a pattern or use your favorite search engine, such as Yahoo or DuckDuckGo, to find one of the thousands of freely available patterns..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of evenly spacing elements in drawing software, I'd use the alignment tools and/or blend tool.

Illustrator has both.

My typical process is:

- draw single object
- clone/duplicate as many as I need
- position one at the beginning and one at the end
- select all then [use the align tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOQ0fnOtkXY)

Answer (score 1):

I made something similar recently in Illustrator. To start out, I created a diagonal line, then copied and pasted it multiple times on my artboard. After I added the desired number of diagonal lines, I used the horizontal and vertical distribution and alignment buttons to evenly distribute and align the lines. For me they are visible by default in the top controls bar after all the lines are selected. If not, turn on Control under your Window tab.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new document and create a single small stripe segment.

Then save it as pattern and use it